# python 3 remove before and after on string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this string `/1B5DB40?full` and I want to convert it to `1B5DB40`.

I need to remove the `?full` and the front `/`

My site won't always have `?full` at the end so I need something that will still work even if the `?full` is not there.

Thanks and hopefully this isn't too confusing to get some help :)

EDIT:
I know I could slice at 0 and 8 or whatever, but the `1B5DB40` could be longer or shorter. For example it could be `/1B5DB4000?full` or `/1B5`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @pvg I updated my question. The string will be different sizes, which is what I cannot figure out. If I slice it at 0 and 8 then it wont work

Comment: Can you slice at "/" and "?" ?

Comment: @falsetru Will this work even if there isnt `?full` since sometimes the string won't have it? Sorry I'm new to python so trying to figure this all out.

Comment: `string[1:].replace("?full", "")`

Comment: Are you actually parsing a part of a URL? because there are library calls that will help you do that

Comment: @BrandonStewart, It will work, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrp) (to remove leading `/`) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (to remove optinal part after `?`):

```
>>> '/1B5DB40?full'.lstrip('/').split('?')[0]
'1B5DB40'

>>> '/1B5DB40'.lstrip('/').split('?')[0]
'1B5DB40'
```

or using [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse('/1B5DB40?full').path.lstrip('/')
'1B5DB40'
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse('/1B5DB40').path.lstrip('/')
'1B5DB40'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lstrip` and `rstrip`:

```
>>> data.lstrip('/').rstrip('?full')
'1B5DB40'
```

This only works as long as you don't have the characters `f`, `u`, `l`, `?`, `/` in the part that you want to extract.

Comment: What if `data` is `'/1Buuuu?full'`?

Comment: @falsetru: You are right, I had no idea about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re

>>> extract = re.compile('/?(.*?)\?full')
>>> print extract.search('/1B5DB40?full').group(1)
1B5DB40
>>> print extract.search('/1Buuuuu?full').group(1)
1Buuuuu
```

Answer (score 1):

What about regular expressions?

```
import re
re.search(r'/(?P<your_site>[^\?]+)', '/1B5DB40?full').group('your_site')
```

In this case it matches everything that is between `'/'` and `'?'`, but you can change it to your specific requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> '/1B5DB40?full'split('/')[1].split('?')[0]
'1B5DB40'
>>> '/1B5'split('/')[1].split('?')[0]
'1B5'
>>> '/1B5DB40000?full'split('/')[1].split('?')[0]
'1B5DB40000'
```

[Split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will simply return a single element list containing the original string if the separator is not found.